# runCommand returns a value, but the result cannot be assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, rhino

The following is a short function to return a file size on a Linux system, run in the rhino shell:

```
function fsize(file){
    var filesize = runCommand("stat","-c %s",file);
    return filesize;
}
```

Running the function returns a value; e.g:

```
fsize('/etc/hosts');
```

returns a file size in bytes

But if I run:

```
var filesize = fsize(testfile);
```

the var `filesize` is "0" when output to the console.

Why is this happening, and how can it be fixed?

To examine variables, I used the function:

```
function output(strings){
    print(strings);
}
```

A sample shell session, showing output:

> ```
> js> var file = "/var/www/javascript/ProgressMon/progressmon.js"
> js> fsize(file);
> 683
> 0
> js> var filesize = fsize(file);
> 683
> js> filesize;
> 0
> js> output(filesize);
> 0
> js>
> ```

Comment: Please include the line of code that behaves differently than you expect (e.g. the "output" line).

Comment: See if the `var filesize` within your function contains anything using `console.log` or `alert`.

Comment: *Where/when* are you calling executing `var filesize = fsize(testfile);` and *where/when* are you trying to output `filesize`? The context is important here. Without it we can only make guesses (and we don't like that).

Comment: From what I see, the `output` function invocation evaluates to `undefined`, but that is not an issue since that function doesn't output to the console but somewhere else... If you want to "output" a variable to the console, just execute it (as an expression). So where does the `output` function output to?

Comment: the output function is just a print command, where i created a function to change the name

Comment: @Cornucopia Well, it seems that your print command doesn't print, doesn't it? `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas well its outputting the 683, but just not to the var?

Comment: Check my latest edit and look closely here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell#runCommand(commandName.2C_.5Barg.2C_....5D_.5Boptions.5D)

Comment: @Cornucopia If `output` is your function, post its code...

Comment: added the output function, i removed the .output following the run command, it still returns the file size, but wont assign it to a var.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW thanks, looking at that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the [`runCommand` documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210625041218/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell#runcommand.28commandname.2c_.5barg.2c_....5d_.5boptions.5d.29), it can be called in the following forms:

```
runCommand(command);
runCommand(command, arg1, ..., argN);
runCommand(command, arg1, ..., argN, options);
```

The sample uses the second form, which prints the output to the terminal but does not capture it in any way that's available to code. In other words, `fsize(testfile)` does not *return* the file size, it prints it.

The result returned by all forms is the exit status of the command, which is what gets assigned to `filesize`.

To capture output, you must use the third form and pass an object with an `output` property, which can be an `java.io.OutputStream` or a string. In this case, you probably want the latter, as that will cause program output to be appended to the property. The function can then call `parseInt` on the output to get the size as a number, rather than a string.

The system call might generate errors. To handle them within `fsize`, you could print error messages and return a negative value to indicate an error. If `runCommand` might throw an exception, the code could be wrapped in a `try-catch` block.

```
function fsize(file){
    var options = {
        output: '',
    };
    try {
        var result = runCommand("stat", "-c", "%s", file, options);
        if (result) {
            print(options.err);
            return -1;
        } else {
            return parseInt(options.output);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        print(err);
        return -1;      
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could let code up the call-stack handle exceptions, and raise an exception for any error generated by the `runCommand` call .

```
function fsize(file){
    var options = {
        output: '',
        err: '',
    };
    if (runCommand("stat", "-c", "%s", file, options)) {
        // note: `SystemError` must be defined, as it's not a standard class
        throw new SystemError(options.err);
    }
    return parseInt(options.output);
}
```

Note that instead of calling `output(filesize);` to print the value of `filesize`, you can evaluate it directly:

> ```
> js> var filesize = fsize(file);
> js> filesize
> 683
> ```

Comment: That works, although

     opt.output
returns the file size in bytes twice... not sure why, also not sure why it didnt work originally,

thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing at this, but it looks like you are running a command via Ajax.  If you were to do:

```
var filesize = fsize(testfile);
alert(filesize);
```

It would be `undefined` as Javascript will continue the code and execute the next line even if it is still waiting on a response from the server.

What you could try doing is adding a timeout, or a callback to the `runCommand()` when it is complete to alert the variable that is returned.

Again, it is just a guess, but that is usually the case when you are dealing with Ajax and Javascript.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, im actually using rhino to run the code, see my above shell output i added

Comment: Yeah I saw that afterwards and realized it.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are expecting to return something, but you never told the function to return anything.

```
function output(strings){
    print(strings);
    //missing return
}
```

So if the function never executed any `return`, it will return `undefined` (this also happens if you just use `return;`)

---

Also, to use this function I think you need to change:

```
var filesize = runCommand("stat","-c %s",file).output();
```

with

```
var filesize = output(runCommand("stat","-c %s",file));
```